# How to go fullscreen when pressedAlt+Enter and maximized window when pressed Esc?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using the following code to switch between full screen and maximized window,

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
  if ((e->key()==Qt::Key_Enter) && (e->modifiers()==Qt::AltModifier))
       this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
  if (e->key()==Qt::Key_Escape)
      if(isFullScreen())
        this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
}
```

but this doesn't work.Can anybudy tell me what's the problem here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use:

```
e->modifiers()==Qt::AltModifier
```

to check key modifiers because the modifiers() function returns flags.
Use something like:

```
e->modifiers()&Qt::AltModifier
```

or

```
(e->modifiers()&Qt::AltModifier)==Qt::AltModifier
```

Comment: Maybe you should use Qt::Key_Return instead of Qt::Key_Enter. See this: [link](http://www.ffuts.org/blog/the-difference-between-qt-key-enter-and-qt-key-r)

Comment: Now we can use `e->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::AltModifier)` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should not use Alt+Enter.

You can change your key to Alt+F or other 'cause Alt+Enter actiually doesn't work.

Comment: I have modified the code for Alt+F,but,I have lineEdits in the UI,when I use Alt+F it directly typed in one of the LineEdit